# Cannot connect to website for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an iOS Enterprise account. I attached my provision file as a link and also my plist using the itms-services protocol. I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with Apache2 server. I already added the Mime types to /etc/mimes.types. When I follow the log I can see the provision gets pulled down, without a problem, and the plist by itself can, but when I use my iPad to pull down the app clicking on items-services protocol link, it doesn't seem to let me download it. It keeps telling me that it can't connect to the URL inside of an iOS pop up box.

I'm using this link (with domain name stubbed out):

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://server.com/apps/StockCountApp.plist">
            Install Stock Count Application</a>
```

Here is my plist:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>assets</key>
                    <array>
                            <dict>
                                    <key>kind</key>
                                    <string>software-package</string>
                                    <key>url</key>
                                    <string>https://server.com/apps/StockCountApp.ipa</string>
                            </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>metadata</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                            <string>com.server.StockCountApp</string>
                            <key>bundle-version</key>
                            <string>0.0.1</string>
                            <key>kind</key>
                            <string>software</string>
                            <key>title</key>
                            <string>StockCount</string>
                    </dict>
            </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can get to the plist using https and i can use the link for the IPA inside of the plist to also get the IPA without a problem, but for some weird reason I can't seem to get the IPA using the itms protocol using an iDevice.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am also facing same issue .If you got solution means pleas provide me .Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plist and links are correct

Check authentication on your server on this page and plist file request.
Because cookies of your browser do not send them to itunes on device. 
Your plist file must be available without auth.

Comment: And if you generate plist programatically on server be sure what content-type = application/xml

Comment: Honestly, it is too late. I already left that job, but will have to check into it next time, if i get the chance to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Antaresm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131605/cannot-connect-to-website-for-iphone-app/23219862#comment21826992_15432133) said `Content-Type` MUST be `application/xml` and NOT `text/xml` as everyone else says!!

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously too late to solve your problem but this note may solve somebody else's problem.

I saw that same message when I forgot to upload the `<appname>.plist` file to the web server. Once I uploaded the `*.plist` file the "`Cannot connect to <domain>`" pop up box went away.

Comment: I'll take a look. Actually didn't solve this problem yet. Doing local installation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another factor (last chance, pulling my hair out) is that the webserver is serving only standard files (html, xml, asp, js, etc). I asked Fasthosts to double check and they modified the config to allow .ipa and .plist to be served as valid file extensions, and finally, it works.